# Empty blank in drop down menu

Tags: php, html, css

I want to align the text to the left but I am having errors saying the syntax is wrong

I want to have an empty blank in the drop down menu and after that all the numbers should come up in the drop down menu

```
 echo '<select name="options">';
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++)
{
    echo "<option value="">".$i."</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
echo "<input type=submit value='Add to Basket'>";
```

Comment: What *"errors"*? Could we see those? As on the last line, you exclude a piece of text from the string that should be **in** the string as it's not `php` code. That's probably the syntax error you are talking about.

Comment: you have syntax error in the last line. near 2nd "

Comment: try this : echo "<p style='text-align:left;'>Enter required Quantity: </p>";

Comment: @Nytrix Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '">"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: In that case you have different code then we are looking at

Comment: You changed your question as well

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your last line.

```
echo "<p style='text-align:left;'>Enter required Quantity:</p>";
```

It was trying to interpret *Enter required Quantity:* as code, rather than output text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the blank option outside the loop, this is how your code should look

```
    <?php



echo "<label>select quantity</label>";
echo "<select name=\"options\">";
echo "<option value=\"\"></option>"; // Blank you can remove the text
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    echo "<option value=\"" . $i . "\">" . $i . "</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add to Basket\">";
?>
```

**Results:**
[image]

Comment: also how would I put text before the drop down menu like "selected quantity required" and then the drop down menu

Comment: Just echo the text in a label tag before the dropdown, please google html forms

Comment: is it like this echo "<label for="male">Male "</label>" and would this go before the for loop and in between those two lines of code 'select name=' and 'option value'

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: @unknown_23 if this helped answer your problem, upvote and mark the question so it can be closed

Answer (score 0):

You need to alternate quotes within quotes. If your echo is bound by double quotes, then use single quotes inside, and vice versa.

Your code should become this (change `option value=""` to `option value=''` :

```
echo '<select name="options">';
echo "<option value=''></option>"; // this adds an empty blank
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++)
{
    echo "<option value=''>".$i."</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
echo "<input type=submit value='Add to Basket'>";
```

Comment: your answer does not answer the question

Comment: updated the answer :) hope it answers both queries now!